# Getting Error 'DB' is not defined when trying to invoke MongoDB with nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql, mongoose-schema

I am totally absolutely novice to MongoDB and this is my first ever venture. I am still scraping around for basic ideas and procedures. Trying to build just a basic sample application with React and MongoDB as backend. I am trying to start the backend part of my project with ***nodemon server*** and getting error message on console.

The error that I am getting is -->

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('playerDB', playerDB);
                                            ^

ReferenceError: playerDB is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\REACT\MyProj\backend\server.js:46:45)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I do not know what I am doing honestly. Just trying random things. When I start mongo.exe and run 
***use playerDB***
it gives me message,

```
switched to db playerDB
```

So what's the trouble? What is wrong?

My server.js code is as such -

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const PORT = 4000;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const playerRoutes = express.Router();

let Player = require('./player.model');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());


mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/playerDB', { useNewUrlParser: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', function () {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});

playerRoutes.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
    Player.find(function (err, todos) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(todos);
        }
    });
});

playerRoutes.route('/add').post(function (req, res) {
    let player = new Player(req.body);
    player.save()
        .then(todo => {
            res.status(200).json({ 'player': 'player added successfully' });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send('adding new player failed');
        });
});

app.use('/playerDB', playerRoutes);

module.exports = mongoose.model('playerDB', playerDB);

app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log("Server is running on Port: " + PORT);
});
```

So which part is wrong? Where is my mistake? When I run mongod.exe it gives me the ready message as

```
2019-09-15T00:41:03.305-0700 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Marking collection config.transactions as collection version: <unsharded>
2019-09-15T00:41:03.306-0700 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

**EDIT -> this is my player model class --> player.model.js,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


let Player = new Schema({
    player_name: {
        type: String
    },
    player_description: {
        type: String
    },
    player_position: {
        type: String
    },
    player_age: {
        type: String
    },
    player_club: {
        type: String
    },
    player_: {
        type: String
    },
    player_isactive: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    player_completed: {
        type: Boolean
    }
});
```

Can someone direct me step by step, sequentially??
Thanks,

Comment: Can you show what code player model have?

Comment: As far as I know, this line: `module.exports = mongoose.model('playerDB', playerDB);` shouldn't be at your `server.js` file. What if you comment out that line and run a test?

Comment: @SandeepPatel certainly I'll update my code, take a look,

Comment: hi @MauricioContreras let me try out your suggestion, 
I'll put that line in the player model js class instead.
I'll revert back,

Comment: Certainly, that line belongs to `player.model.js` file (put it at the end of that file), otherwise you aren't exporting the module the right way. And the line must be: `module.exports = mongoose.model('player', Player);`, where `'player'` would be the name of the Model for Mongoose, and `Player` is the name of the Schema you've created above.

Comment: ok, @MauricioContreras let me try out this change,

Comment: And the line must be: `module.exports = mongoose.model('player', Player);`, where `'player'` would be the name of the Model for Mongoose, and `Player` is the name of the Schema you've created above. Try it out and comment the results.

Comment: ok, now error is -->
  
module.exports = mongoose.model('player', Player);
                                      ^
ReferenceError: Player is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\REACT\MyProj\backend\player.model.js:3:43)    
@MauricioContreras

Comment: It shows `line 3`: `player.model.js:3:43`. That means you are putting that line early in the module, move it to the bottom of the file. That line must be the last one of your file. Try it again and comment results.

Comment: well this is my entire backend project basically, if that helps to replicate-->

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqxwD_-HSbSQgR3hvA9p0U_voGvS?e=dghkRA

Comment: woohoooHOOO works like a charm!  @MauricioContreras ,
my output --->


[nodemon] 1.19.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
(node:8796) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
Server is running on Port: 4000
MongoDB database connection established successfully

Comment: I'm glad been helpful.

Comment: just 1 more thing, trying to add players now to the MongoDB.
THROUGH POSTMAN.
This is what I am setting -> localhost:4000/playerDB/add           [post request] and
in the body: 

{
 "player_name":"Didier Drogba",
 "player_description":"Brawny, cunning, determined and a heart for attempting the most impossible audacious! The one and only!",
 "player_position":"Striker",
 "player_age":"42",
 "player_club":"Chelsea FC",
 "player_":"Hall of Famer",
 "player_isactive":"False",
 "player_completed":"True"
}


Response --> 400 adding new player failed             @MauricioContreras

Comment: You will need to post another question, that's other issue.

Comment: ok, will do, @MauricioContreras thanks again,